# Print list of lists, Prolog

Tags: list, grid, prolog

I got this grid:

```
tab([[s,f,f,f,s,f,f,f,s],
     [f,s,f,f,f,f,f,s,f],
     [f,f,s,f,f,f,s,f,f],
     [f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f],
     [s,f,f,f,m,f,f,f,s],
     [f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f],
     [f,f,s,f,f,f,s,f,f],
     [f,s,f,f,f,f,f,s,f],
     [s,f,f,f,s,f,f,f,s]]).
```

I want to print in the screen without brackets and commas.
By the way I can't print it right with or without them.

These are the print rules:

```
viewTab([]).
viewTab([H|T]) :-
    printList(H),
    viewTab(T).

printList([]) :-
    nl.
printList([H|T]) :-
    write(H),
    write(' | '),
    printList(T).
```

I call it in the Prolog's terminal like:

```
?- viewTab(X), tab(X).
```

I can't print a thing, and I get an infinite loop at:

```
printList([]) :-
   nl.
```

Can you help me find my mistake?

Or some tips to make the code easier to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `viewTab/1` is **not** a purely logical predicate: it has a side effect, and it does not terminate for if its argument is a variable.

For example:

```
?- listing(foo).

foo([]).
foo([_|A]) :-
    foo(A).

true.

?- foo(X).
X = [] ;
X = [_G256] ;
X = [_G256, _G259] ;
X = [_G256, _G259, _G262] ;
X = [_G256, _G259, _G262, _G265] ;
X = [_G256, _G259, _G262, _G265, _G268] . % and so on
```

So this:

```
?- viewTab(X), tab(X).
```

Puts a list in `X`, then `tab(X)` fails, and you are back at `viewTab(X)`, ad infinitum.

You should try:

```
?- tab(X), viewTab(X).
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!**

[Definite clause grammars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) are a versatile, logical way of processing input/output.

For a start, read [this well-written DCG primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg.html) by [Markus Triska, also known as @mat on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat)!

---

Right now, as a quick fix, use the built-in predicate [`format/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dformat.html) like this:

```
?- X = [a,b,c], format('~s~n',[X]).
abc                                    % output via side-effect
X = [a, b, c].                         % query succeeds
```

Comment: Your `format` won't work unless all elements are "chars" (one-letter atoms)

Comment: @Boris. Right! But is that a tough restriction for a quick fix? Codes are *so* passe...

Comment: I would actually really like it if `format` could just take a list of terms and print them out as if _each_ term was passed to `write`. Not possible at the moment.